# De-coupling Model and Separating Public/Private Methods in Objective-C (Protocols vs Public/Private Headers)

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, protocols

I'm currently building a game in Objective-C (for iPhone).

For this I'm slightly breaking MVC for performance/complexity reasons and giving the view (renderer) a direct reference to the model. This is because it's supposed to run at 60fps and is constantly updating itself based on the model's state.

I have properties that are read-write in my model's header files, due to other classes in my model needing to access and set those. But they should act as readonly for my view. So I have the issue of needing to separate public/private methods.

I think a typical approach to this is to have a normal "X.h" header, which the view will import and a separate "X_private.h" for the other model classes to use internally.

A Java developer friend of mine suggested a different approach using protocols.

He suggested creating protocols of NSObject like "IX.h", which would contain the public methods the view references. Then simply having the class (X.h/X.m) setup with private (in terms of the whole model) methods on it's header and having that class implement the protocol.

This seems pretty cool as it adds a further layer of abstraction. Now if I decide to change the underlying model classes and how they work, I can do so as long as they still implement the public protocol. The view doesn't even know what classes the model really uses underneath.

I don't see any obvious downside to this approach, but it's not something I've done before in Objective-C.

Is this a good approach or am I missing something?

Are there are other good approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

What your friend has suggested is perfectly fine. However, the read-write properties of your model are still available for access and might be used by mistake.

A better approach that I can think of is using class extension/anonymous category. In this approach your default interface of the model class will contain only the read accessors.

Model

```
@interface Model:NSObject

-(NSNumber *)readProperty1;
-(NSString *)readProperty2;

@end
```

Model+ReadWrite.h

```
@interface Model()

@property(strong) NSString *property1;
@property(strong) NSString *property2;

@end
```

By importing `Model+ReadWrite.h` in your Model.m or the other models that you require you can access all the properties while the general interface of your model only exposes the readonly method.

Comment: This seems like a standard idea too, along with using public/private headers. However, doesn't this still mean I have to import the Model class directly? Whereas, with the protocol method, I could change the underlying class still as it's just a non-class specific list of methods.

Comment: This works more or less the same way. Since your default interface only provides accessor methods you can still go ahead and change your model however you like. It's just a matter of opinion. I would be more worried about misuse of my readwrite methods, while putting them under a separate header would make it clear to others that I dont wan't people messing around with it.

Comment: The issue is it still means you're referencing the model class specifically. Unlike in the protocol which provides another layer of abstraction. The underlying mechanics that return the methods of the protocol could even be split amongst multiple classes. This could be changed without any refactoring outside the model.